# 'mscoree' namespace not found

Tags: c#, windows

I am coding a C# and need to use the mscoree namespace. After doing some looking around the internet apparently you get this by installing .NET Framework 3.5 through the optionalfeatures.exe on windows. I already have this installed as shown by the screenshot. And after a PC restart it is still showing that I don't have the namespace. Is there any other way to obtain this namespace?

`using mscoree;

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no namespace named `mscoree` in .NET  - so what prompted this? (furthermore, .NET Framework 3.5 (which uses .NET Framework's 2.0 CLR) is obsolete - and its components cannot be used by later .NET versions)

Comment: @Dai When i was researching about this project that i wanted to start doing a lot of them was using mscoree.
`using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.linq; using System.Runtime.InteropServices; using mscoree;`
this above code is found in a github repo i was looking at when i was researching into the project

Comment: _I am coding a C# and need to use the mscoree namespace._ Says who?

Comment: Bruh, I am delving into something i have little experience on and is researching about it just so I don't start coding it with 0 knowledge. I know C# just not the library that needs to be used for it. Which is Rage. Now the thing I am trying to code is a Common dll so I don't have to keep on copying and pasting the same code into all my other things for the same thing. There is a function that I am trying to make that according to every single github repo and websites i found is using mscoree.

Comment: _"There is a function that I am trying to make that according to every single github repo and websites i found is using mscoree."_ - Please provide a link to an example repo which does this, _**bruh**_.

Comment: https://github.com/Albo1125/Albo1125-Common/blob/master/Albo1125.Common/AppDomainHelper.cs

Comment: @BobDylan [See the `.csproj` file](https://github.com/Albo1125/Albo1125-Common/blob/master/Albo1125.Common/Albo1125.Common.csproj), it's a COM Reference: `<COMReference Include="mscoree">`. The namespace [is generated by the compiler when it generates COM types (interfaces, proxies, etc) from a TLB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/cominterop). I note that the project you linked to will not work on modern .NET (e.g. .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5, .NET 7, etc), it will only run on .NET Framework 4.x. I don't see any point to using this at all...

Comment: I am not really trying to use it use it. Trust trying to use it as a reference if I get an error I can't solve myself. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has been answered by @Dai

The mscoree is a COM Reference as seen in the .csproj file of the github repo linked
(https://github.com/Albo1125/Albo1125-Common/blob/master/Albo1125.Common/AppDomainHelper.cs)

The namespace is generated by the compiler when it generates COM types (interfaces, proxies, etc) from a TLB.